# MVC Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I'm fetching the data from database table like "select Name Test1, Age Test2" and passing the result to render in the grid. Here i want column name to be displayed as Name and Age. Can any one please provide the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Title` setting of the column to set the text displayed in the grid header.